# Google plus share 'popup' css bug

Tags: html, css, google-plus-one

I have tried to implement the google plus button into our site, but the popup bubble is really weird. 
[image]

I have used the following code:

```
<g:plusone annotation="none"></g:plusone>
<!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

We uses some table on our page , and it seems it resets the google plus button's css. ( I know, it's weird to use table as a  part of the design, so we use them correctly  and not for the layout! )

Because we need that css code, how can I redefine the css of the google+ share bubble?

It's so important, I have seen some details like .pls-topTail, .pls-vertShimLeft, .pls-contentLeft , but any correct documentation for this  I haven't seen yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a table:not(.gc-bubbleDefault) into the css  everywhere where previously just a  table was defined resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) to inspect the css of the "google" popup.

Comment: i always use firebug, but this popup disappears very fast, so I can't see what happen. It's really hard to inspect, just try it :)

Comment: You could try to push the pause button on the script tab of firebug. At the moment I cannot figger out how to run your example in my browser. I have now a white page :-)

Comment: Hm, not a bad idea! I haven't used that before, but currently I can see the code what I get back from the google.